# Qual melhor pratica para envio de autorização via HTTP header

Tags: php, api, rest, http-headers

Estou desenvolvendo um api rest, preciso passar alguns dados em todas as requisições que são basicamente a autorização necessária. Os dados são:
Token,unidade e um id.
Qual seria melhor forma de passar isso via header. tentei algo assim:

```
Authorization: MinhaAuth Token="0PN5J17HBGZHT7JJ3X82", unidade="aaa"
```

Porem não consigo recuperar esses dados, separadamente, no php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tentei algo assim: `Authorization: MinhaAuth Token="0PN5J17HBGZHT7JJ3X82", unidade="aaa"`. Porem não consigo recuperar esses dados, separadamente, no php.

Respondendo a pergunta acima...

#### Configuração do Servidor

No `Apache`, basta adicionar o código abaixo no seu arquivo `.htaccess`

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

No `Nginx`, basta adicionar o código abaixo no seu arquivo de configuração. No meu caso ele fica em `/etc/nginx/sites-available`

```
fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;
```

#### Capturando no PHP

Você pode fazer a captura dos elementos com a função `preg_match`. Basta fazer o seguinte:

```
<?php

preg_match('/^(?<Auth>\w+).*Token="(?<Token>.*?)".*unidade="(?<Unidade>.*)"/', $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], $result);

print_r( $result );
print_r( $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] );
```

#### Explicação do Regex

> `^(?<Auth>\w+)` Aqui ele vai pegar todo o valor alfanumérico que está no inicio do `Header`. No seu caso `MinhaAuth`

> `Token="(?<Token>.*?)"` Aqui ele vai capturar todo o valor que está entre " (aspas) que venha depois de `Token=`. No seu caso `0PN5J17HBGZHT7JJ3X82`

> `unidade="(?<Unidade>.*)"` Aqui ele vai capturar todo o valor que está entre " (aspas) que venha depois de `unidade=`. No seu caso `aaa`

> `?<Token>` Essa parte significa que é para ele criar um array com o índice `Token`, por exemplo. Dessa forma você consegue capturar utilizando `$result['Token']`

Comment: Funcionou obrigado, porem ele ta retornando repetido o token e etc um com o nome 'token" mesmo e outro como '0'

Comment: @IgorOliveira É assim mesmo que o `preg_match` funciona. Não é erro.